# buffer overflow exploit experiment, unexpected result

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

I am doing an analysis of special cases of UB, for the purpose of learning about security leaks via exploits of buffer overflows.

I have trouble understanding the result of an experiment wiht intentionally proked UB. Where I believe that the overflow of a buffer (which lies between another buffer and my detector variable) overfwrites both, the other buffer and the detector.

In short: What could be the reason for the value 49 of the variable 'value' after

```
strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);
```

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8];
    char buffer_two[8];
    strcpy(buffer_one, "one");
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two");

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* Copy first argument into buffer_two. */

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

---

Result:

```
./overflow_example AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0xbff2db0c and contains  'two' 
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0xbff2db14 and contains  'one' 
[BEFORE] value is at 0xbff2db1c and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY copying 17 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0xbff2db0c and contains  'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1' 
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0xbff2db14 and contains  'AAAAAAAA1' 
[AFTER] value is at 0xbff2db1c and is 49 (0x00000031)
```

the stack of memory go up. It mean we override the value of buffer_one. But i don't know why value of 'value' was effected

Comment: Why do you think `value` strictly must not be affected? Does the standard require any particular memory layout for automatic variables?

Comment: You have buffer overflows, which lead to undefined behaviour.  Anything is possible.  The question isn't interesting because the code has UB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about uninteresting undefined behaviour.

Comment: As mentioned, it is UB. But I have no problems imagining one way how the 49 (ASCII value for '1') ends up one byte behind the overflowing buffer `buffer_one', which is one byte shorter than the overflow of the buffer before it. Your code seems fine tuned to provoke, detect and document in detail exactly that special way of UB I am thinking of. So why are you having problems imagining it?

Comment: my problem is i think address of buffer_two between address of buffer_one and address of 'value', so when overflow, there is only one variable was overrided. But actually, address of buffer_two is below of others. This is stupid mistake

Comment: You printed the values of the addresses. What makes you think that 0x0c is between 0x1a and 0x1c?

Comment: You are using Stack allocation, which stores back to front. You can make your arrays static or use ˋmallocˋ instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your exploit experiment you seem to have lost track of the order of buffers and variable.
Your output (together with variable declarations in the code) clearly shows:

- buffer_two, size 8, address 0x...0c
- buffer_one, size 8, address 0x...14
- value     , size 4, address 0x...1c

(Size of value is guess, but irrelevant, assuming it has the LSB on lowest byte address.)

When buffer_two overflows by 9 bytes, it will fill buffer_one completely, first byte of value with '1' == 49 and second byte of value with 0.

To repeat, all of that is, strictly speaking, UB and therefor wild guessing. But that is the normal environment of exploits, which you are probably aware of.